# Flexible, user-generated text in fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm working on a scholarly edition of a philosophical manuscript and looking for a way to have fancyhdr display the page break of the original MS.

In the text I put "|" at the position of the page break, and now – naive as I am – I am looking for a command to (manually) put an information like "1|2" in the header (right on even, left on odd pages).

I hope that my English is not too bad, and that I did express the question clearly enough.

Comment: Your 1|2 is standing to say that this the first page over a total number of 2 pages or that on this current printed page you have the 1 and 2 pages (or at least part of them) of the former manuscript?

Comment: The latter, Gonzalo Medina understood my incomplete description in the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `\mymark` command to place the rule in the text and also to place the desired text in the header; for example, `\mymark{7}{8}` places a rule in the document body and also places  `7|8` in the header (if the second number is always the first plus one, the definition can be simplified a little, but this was not clear in the question):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % just for the example
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\def\mymark{}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\mymark}
\fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand\MyBreak[2]{%
  \renewcommand\mymark{\footnotesize#1\,\rule{0.4pt}{1.6ex}\,#2}~\rule[-.3ex]{1pt}{2ex}}

\newcommand\Text{this is just some text for the example} % just to generate text for the example
\begin{document}

\Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\MyBreak{1}{2}\ \Text\ \Text
\clearpage
\Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ 
\Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\MyBreak{4}{5}\ \Text\ \Text

\end{document}
```

An image of the first page:

[image]

An image of the second page:

[image]

A variation; `\MyBreak` has now one mandatory argument and one optional argument. If used in the form `\MyBreak{}` (the mandatory argument is empty), it just removes the text from the header; otherwise, used as in `\MyBreak{<number>}` it prints a rule in the text and also the header in the form `<number>|<number>+1`. If the character `u` is used in the optional argument as in `\MyBreak[u]{<number>}`, then the header will only contain `<number>`;  If the character `t` is used in the optional argument as in `\MyBreak[t]{<number>}`, then the header will contain `<number>|<number>+1|<number>+2` See the following example; an additional `\MyRule` command was provided to simply draw a vertical rule in the text without generating marks:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % just for the example
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\def\mymark{}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\mymark}
\fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand\MyRule{~\rule[-.3ex]{1pt}{2ex}}
\newcommand\MyBreak[2][]{%
\ifx#1u\relax
  \renewcommand\mymark{\footnotesize#2}%
\else
\ifx#1t\relax
  \renewcommand\mymark{\footnotesize#2\,\rule{0.4pt}{1.6ex}\,\number\numexpr#2+1\,\rule{0.4pt}{1.6ex}\,\number\numexpr#2+2\relax}~\rule[-.3ex]{1pt}{2ex}%
\else
  \if\detokenize{#2}\relax\relax
  \renewcommand\mymark{}%
  \else
  \renewcommand\mymark{\footnotesize#2\,\rule{0.4pt}{1.6ex}\,\number\numexpr#2+1\relax}~\rule[-.3ex]{1pt}{2ex}%
  \fi
\fi
\fi
}

\newcommand\Text{this is just some text for the example} % just to generate text for the example
\begin{document}

\Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\MyBreak{3}\ \Text\ \Text
\clearpage
\Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ 
\Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\MyBreak[u]{4}\ \Text\ \Text
\clearpage
\MyBreak{}
\Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ 
\clearpage
\Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\MyBreak[t]{7} \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\MyRule\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ \Text\ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I thought of. And yes, I forgot to mention, that the second number is always the first plus one. Another thing is: If there is a chapter, that has, for example, only a half page at the end before a "regular" page break (beginning of a new chapter), and there is no MyBreak on it, fancyhdr displays "3|4" although there is only text from MS-page 4 (while the last MyBreak is on the previous pdf-page.

Comment: @michael please see my updated answer; with this new version, you only spacify one value; use an empty argument `\MyBreak{}` if you want to "kill" the header text at some point.

Comment: This is really good! I like the simplicity of the mybreak-input and the possibility to "kill" it – I never could have imagined by myself. So I barely dare to ask for another "plus": Do you also have an idea for a mybreak-command (within the variant) in order to have only one page number? The problem is: After the last \MyBreak{4} with the output "4|5" the current chapter of the edition may end on half a page with text only from page 5 of the MS. So I neither want "4|5" nor "" (blank) input in fancyhdr, but "5".

Comment: @michael answer updated; now you have three possibilities: `\MyBreak{}` (no header); `\MyBreak{5}` gives `5|6`, and `\MyBreak[u]{5}` gives only `5`.

Comment: @ Gonzalo Two more things: \MyBreak[u]{5} draws (like the other commands) a line in the text which I don't need, because there is no page break of the MS on the current pdf page (which is why I only need one page number in mymark). Second: When I have two page breaks of the MS on one pdf page, mymark displays the last MyBreak (e.g. 4|5). Correct for my purpuse would be e.g. 3|4|5 or |4|5 or |4, 5 or 3–5.

Comment: @michael answer updated; now the new variant `\MyBreak[t]{<number>}` prints three numbers in the mark and `\MyRule` draws a rule in the text without generating marks. Will you need in some cases more than three numbers or is this the maximum?

Comment: I don't think so. But – I now come to reconsider my question, and see the full consequences of its wording: I know that  I did not ask for a (automated) counter, but nevertheless, is it possible to have LaTeX controll which data it puts into mymark? To have it count the MyBreak commands on one pdf page and than »decide«: »101« / »101|102« / »101–103«? I should have asked earlier, my apologies. This MS is 400 pages long.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,heightrounded,headheight=16pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}         % put things headers and footers and we plan misuse it ;)
\usepackage{lipsum}           % for sample text
\usepackage{lastpage}         % Will get last page number for you    
%
\fancypagestyle{mypage}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LO]{Page \thepage\ \rule[-1ex]{.5pt}{3.5ex} \pageref{LastPage}}
    \fancyhead[RE]{Page \thepage\ \rule[-1ex]{.5pt}{3.5ex} \pageref{LastPage}}    
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mypage}   % activate page style
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Harish, my description was too bad; Gonzalo nevertheless had the right intuition.

Comment: @michael No problem. You can say thanks by upvoting. Also please consider accepting (by clicking the tick mark below vote count) Gonzalo's answer if it helped you. :)